# not able to download inter dependency in maven

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am trying to download dependencies serenity-core 1.9.3 having dependency on asciidoctor-java-integration 0.4 which in turn having dependency on JRuby Complete 1.7.4. My problem is JRuby Complete 1.7.4 is not available in company repository. So it is giving error 403. 
Is there any way to configure pom to take available version of JRuby Complete or set pom to download from central maven repository if not available in company repository.

Comment: You can manually download this library from the maven repository, here is the link http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.4/jruby-complete-1.7.4.jar

Comment: what to do for production. how to manage interdependencies for production to download correct jar available in repository.

Comment: If your company repository does not contain this artifacts than you should contact the responsible department and request it or start the procedure to get it...